# regex for specific fileName patterns

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Hi I had situtation with `frame02_0046.tiff` for which I figured out the following regex  `^(.*)(\d+)([^\d]*)$` however I have another pattern of names `frame1.03.png` to `frame5.03.png`
 how can in the regex I can include both the name pattern

```
    pattern = '^(.*)(\d+)([^\d]*)$'
    patternExpr = re.compile(pattern)
```

Comment: You pattern already includes both kind of names https://regex101.com/r/WNWmu6/1

Comment: @FedericoPiazza then why does this code here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/169115/22943  : is not wrapping the second one as part of sequence

Comment: Your pattern is so broad, it will match everything that has at least 1 number. Even a single number

Comment: Well, your regex probably is doing something that you don't want. Your regex is capture whatever and the last digit and whatever. So, What would you like to match/capture? Do you want to capture the name, first digits, second digits and ext? Your question is a bit unclear to me

Comment: I want `frame1` the name to be `frame` and frame number to be `1` unlike its `0046` in `frame02_0046.tiff`

Comment: Try [`^(.*\D)(\d+)\.([^.]*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/0E70sd/1)

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the comment, your regex is "bad" for the purpose you have.

You can use this regex instead:

```
^([a-z]*?)(\d+)[_.](\d+)\.[a-z]+
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/6pHdlb/2)**

Note the flags I used in the above link.

Match information

```
Match 1
Full match  0-17    `frame02_0046.tiff`
Group 1.    0-5 `frame`
Group 2.    5-7 `02`
Group 3.    8-12    `0046`
Match 2
Full match  18-31   `frame1.03.png`
Group 1.    18-23   `frame`
Group 2.    23-24   `1`
Group 3.    25-27   `03`
Match 3
Full match  32-45   `frame5.03.png`
Group 1.    32-37   `frame`
Group 2.    37-38   `5`
Group 3.    39-41   `03`
```

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz I don't have the time for the moment, but if you need the code for my regex, go to the link and enter in the Code Generator section